# Is it possible to enable ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled=true for entire application

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

Is there any way to enable `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled = true` for entire application or do I have to set it for every single control in my WPF application manually?

I do not think restyling every control is a good solution.

Comment: You can always create a Style for `FrameworkElement`, wouldn't that apply to all elements in the visual tree?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override the property metadata for `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled` and set its default value to `true (by default value is false)` and it will apply to all the controls in your application.

Put this code in your `App.xaml.cs`

```
static App()
{
    ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Control),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx)) and static method `ToolTipService.SetShowOnDisabled` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.setshowondisabled.aspx)).

I created simple class to iterate through all elements and set `ShowOnDisabled` property to `True`.

```
class ToolTipServiceHelper
{       
    public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);                
            ToolTipService.SetShowOnDisabled(childVisual, true);
            EnumVisual(childVisual);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToolTipServiceHelper ttsh = new ToolTipServiceHelper();
        ttsh.EnumVisual(this.Content as Visual);
    }
}
```